# How to run crone job every hour and minute

Tags: cron, node-cron

I would like to schedule a job to fetch users from other server. I would like every hour and minute specified. For that, I have used [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

For example: If I specify 2h and 5min, I would like my job to run like:

Start - **13H**

1. **14h 05m** -next
2. **16h 10m** -next
3. **18h 15m** -next

...etc